# Soap Signing in Clojure

Tags: xml, soap, clojure

I am working with an API that requires all SOAP calls to be signed.  I have looked into the documentation from Java on how to sign SOAP calls using Programming With the Java XML Digital Signature API.

I am consistently running into the following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: newCanonicalizationMethod for class org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.

I know that the issue is with sending the parameters to the newCanonocalizationMethod.  I am following the flow per Java, but I am still running into this issue.

Here is my code.

```
(let [fac (XMLSignatureFactory/getInstance "DOM") 
      dm (doto (.. fac (newDigestMethod (DigestMethod/SHA1) nil))) 
      bk "" 
      ref (.. fac (newReference bk dm)) 
      cm (CanonicalizationMethod/INCLUSIVE) 
      c14 C14NMethodParameterSpec 
      in (.. fac (newCanonicalizationMethod cm c14))])
```

Here is the full function code:  I have just started the process of creating the signature section per this site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html

```
(defn create-signature
  []
  (let [fac (XMLSignatureFactory/getInstance "DOM")
        dm (doto (.. fac (newDigestMethod (DigestMethod/SHA1) nil)))
        bk ""
        ref (.. fac (newReference bk dm))
        cm CanonicalizationMethod/INCLUSIVE
        c14 C14NMethodParameterSpec
        si (..
             fac
             (newSignedInfo
               (..
                 fac
                 (newCanonicalizationMethod
                   cm
                   C14NMethodParameterSpec))
               (..
                 fac
                 (newSignatureMethod
                   (SignatureMethod/RSA_SHA1) nil))
               (.. java.util.Collections (singletonList ref))))
        ]
        ))
```

If you run  reflect on the factory, you get this as a response:

```
{:name newCanonicalizationMethod,
 :return-type javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod,
 :declaring-class
 org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory,
 :parameter-types
 [java.lang.String
  javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec],
 :exception-types
 [java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
  java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException],
 :flags #{:public}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `CanonicalizationMethod/INCLUSIVE` - ie no parens?

Comment: @Chris - I did try without the parens and I still get the same error.

Comment: You must be calling `newCanonicalizationMethod` with the wrong number of args, or at least one of the args must be of the wrong type. Can you provide the signature for `newCanonicalizationMethod` in your question?

Comment: @Chris - I figured that the args where of the wrong type.  I added all of that functions code and the result of running reflect on the factory.

Comment: Isn't `C14NMethodParameterSpec` a class you need to create an instance of, and pass that instance to the `newCanonicalizationMethod` method?

Comment: @Chris - I thought that using C14NMethodParameterSpec was creating the instance.  If I run reflect on it, I get: {:bases #{javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec},
 :flags #{:interface :public :abstract},
 :members #{}}

If I pprint the it out I get the follow:

javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec

It looks like it is creating an instance of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150489/discussion-between-chris-murphy-and-adobe-flex-coder-0622).

Comment: @Chris - Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to generate all of the java methods in a custom Java class.  The issue was the Java method was looking for a certain type of parameter.  The code says to generate it using (Java type)null, which doesn't compile in Clojure.

I was using this website to generate the XML signing [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).

After creating the custom class, I compiled and imported into the Clojure project.

Lesson Learned: When working with certain java classes, it is best to use pure Java instead of Java Interop.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I learnt is that if you want this Java code:

```java
fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);
```

You can do this in Clojure:

```clj
(let [^C14NMethodParameterSpec c14 nil]
 (.newCanonicalizationMethod fac CanonicalizationMethod/INCLUSIVE c14))
```

I hope this helps!